Python exercise to learn - spiral circular shape
I’m trying to use bmesh extrusion and Matrix to do some spiral shape like this :

I would like to start from a circle (like it is described on the picture)
Here where I’m stuck:
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import pi

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_circle(
                        bm,
                        cap_ends=False,
                        radius=0.5,
                        segments=24)


edges_ext = [ele for ele in bm.edges
                if isinstance(ele, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]

steps = 12
Ry = Matrix.Rotation(-pi/(steps), 4, 'Y')
T = Matrix.Translation((3,0,0))
My = T @ Ry @ T.inverted()  

for i in range(steps):
    extruded = bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(bm, edges=edges_ext)
    verts_extruded = [ele for ele in extruded["geom"]
        if isinstance(ele, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
    edges_extruded = [ele for ele in extruded["geom"]
        if isinstance(ele, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix= My, verts=verts_extruded)
    edges_ext = edges_extruded

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()


obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Object", me)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)


It seems ok to rotate the circle around a small radius but
I cannot do all the remaining matrix operations on the extruded verts (translate and rotate around big circle)
Any advices or tips or tricks?
PS: I asked a similar question on another site but unfortunately I didn't get any answers... If it's not here that I can ask this type of question either could you direct me to a site where can I find the answer?
Thank you very much

Hi there. Please post a complete and executable script. The import statements were missing, and it's just annoying to figure out what to import from where if you just want to try it out. Cheers!

OK my bad ! thank you for the remark.

Hi. In the first step, I would try to create just one spiral. If you want to continue your approach, you must rotate each circle that you extrude slightly around the Z axis. The lower part of a loop (=1/2 segment of the spiral as shown in the screenshot) must be rotated in one direction and the upper part in the other. The centre of rotation is on the other side of the starting point (=right end of the model in the screenshot). Then you have a spiral segment & you can create multiple of them. Each segment must be moved along the Y axis to create a spiral...

Another approach would be to just create a spiral, then extrude it and bend it with the Simple Deform modifier ;-). Probably you could calculate the bending with a matrix rotation immediately. But I have no idea how far each point of the spiral has to be rotated to get a 360° bent spiral.

Thank you for your answers !
I continue to search for a code solution ... I haven't managed to put the theory into practice yet ;-)

Ignore my first comment. You don't need to rotate parts of the spiral loops. You can create a spiral by just using bmesh.ops.translate() to move the circle loops along the Y-axis. I cannot help you with the bending. My linear algebra is too poor for that.
